# HTTPConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=y): Read timed out. (read timeout=None) on nginx server?

Tags: python, nginx, centos7, gunicorn, supervisord

From my python script there are multiple API calls and APIs are in same application!
I am using django framework!
Through  `python3 manage.py runserver`
it was working fine!

But in centos7 VM with nginx server, supervisor, gunicorn it is not working after calling the third API!

This error appeared:

```
The complete exception is provided below:
<class 'requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout'>
HTTPConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=y): Read timed out. (read timeout=None)
```

In nginx error log only this error:

```
[error] 12020#12020: *133 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
```

Need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a resolution!

Actually it was for the timeout of gunicorm and nginx.

My script take more than 30 seconds so update my gunicorn config file!

Here is the configuration:

```
[program:project]
command = gunicorn -c /opt/project/gunicorn_config.py project.wsgi -t 300
directory = project directory
user = user
```

Also the nginx configuration need to add this proxy settings:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
}
```

Thanks! Hopefully this will help if anyone face same kind of problem!